# How to keep POSIXct format when appending string to date item in list?

Tags: r

Here the time is added to list and list converted to string:

```
str(list(Sys.time()))
```

Output is :

```
  POSIXct[1:1], format: "2017-11-10 21:22:56"
```

How to paste string to list item and keep format ?
This should be outputted :

```
  List of 1
  $ : Time : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2017-11-10 21:22:56"
```

I've tried :

```
str(list(paste("time" , Sys.time())))
str(list(c("time" , Sys.time())))
```

But the outputs are :

```
> str(list(paste("time" , Sys.time())))
List of 1
$ : chr "time 2017-11-10 21:23:23"
> str(list(c("time" , Sys.time())))
List of 1
$ : chr [1:2] "time" "1510349011.98052"
```

Comment: The output you want probably can't be done with `str`. Why do you want that exact output? Do you understand how characters and numbers are pasted together in R? Or the difference between `c()` and `list()`?

Comment: @Spacedman I want this output as I'm not sure why the output changes when I use 'c' or' paste'. There is no particular reason other than the result is not what I expect.

Answer (score 6):

```
str(list(paste("time" , Sys.time())))
```

This is a list of length 1, the 1 element is from `paste`, which is going to return a character string, because that's what `paste`s job is. So `str` reports a list of length 1 of chr type.

```
str(list(c("time" , Sys.time())))
```

This is also a list of length 1, the 1 element is a vector (created by `c`) of the string "time" and a `POSIXct` object from `Sys.time()`. Vectors can only store one kind of thing, so R has to convert everything to characters.

Interestingly the way POSIXct elements in a vector are converted to chr depends on what's the first element in the vector:

```
> str(c("this",Sys.time()))
 chr [1:2] "this" "1510353128.84358"

> str(c(Sys.time(),"this"))
 POSIXct[1:2], format: "2017-11-10 22:33:13" NA
 Warning message:
 In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Because R is using the first element to figure out which conversion method to use. If the first element is a character, it uses `as.character.default` which converts POSIXt objects to numbers because deep down *they are just numbers*, and `as.character.default` doesn't understand POSIXt timestamps:

```
> as.character.default(Sys.time())
[1] "1510353378.21108"
```

If the first element, or all the elements, are POSIX objects then you do get a formatted timestamp:

```
> as.character.POSIXct(Sys.time())
Error in as.character.POSIXct(Sys.time()) : 
  could not find function "as.character.POSIXct"
> as.character.POSIXt(Sys.time())
[1] "2017-11-10 22:36:30"
```

This fails:

```
> str(c(Sys.time(),"this"))
 POSIXct[1:2], format: "2017-11-10 22:33:13" NA
 Warning message:
 In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

because its trying to call `as.POSIXlt.POSIXct` on a string "this":

```
> as.POSIXlt.POSIXct("this")
[1] NA
Warning message:
In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct("this") : NAs introduced by coercion
>
```

Clear? Probably not. Basically you should figure out what you want and format data elements into character before you start pasting strings together.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to do string manipulation on the captured output:

```
writeLines(sub('$ : ', '$: time :', capture.output(str(list(Sys.time()))), fixed=T))
## List of 1
## $: time :POSIXct[1:1], format: "2017-11-10 16:34:47"
```

Although I have to say I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do this for.